# Is there a way to distingush inline picture and picture attachment via Gmail API

Tags: imap, gmail-api, email-attachments, mime

I fetched two emails from Gmail via their APIs, one contains an inline picture, the other contains an picture attachment. See their HTTP response below.

By comparing these two sections, I am not able to tell which picture is attached and which is inline. "Content-Disposition" shows that both are attachments, though one of them is actually an inline photo.

Is there a way to identify inline pictures with the [response](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) from Gmail API?

```
// inline
      {
        "partId": "2",
        "mimeType": "image/heic",
        "filename": "image_50410497.JPG",
        "headers": [
          {
            "name": "Content-Type",
            "value": "image/heic; name=\"image_50410497.JPG\""
          },
          {
            "name": "Content-Disposition",
            "value": "attachment; filename=\"image_50410497.JPG\""
          },
          {
            "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
            "value": "base64"
          },
          {
            "name": "X-Attachment-Id",
            "value": "18334b929992fd46a211"
          },
          {
            "name": "Content-ID",
            "value": "\u003c18334b929992fd46a211\u003e"
          }
        ],
        "body": {
          "attachmentId": "ANGjdJ8FshN6fd_2OoZEttwPYHk_8q1mVOJevilskBM-6yOZZ6aMMSMblU3Vo5pw-V1_SeDzxkVx0zOg5R-9fGkaSGvGzd6Wi9yVBe4dAn03HDCghyUWFC2jyodeWYmttzzaXyCNRUVPdVxmO7l8yTaeEsQ4Ep1Ze7Nc3bnLNozWHeKZQHQLqGyfLKDdEI1GKjT8X6OuyEY6EWMo8djE30c-BvYjuY95vmomjkjzfoIqTFfpUlMMktNUfvC1SZMHL0arymXmTTM6uVg5N0U2TngVfbKNx0x8hI0bhccB-AiIhwrSqCxM_CZkyXrGRcY",
          "size": 2607632
        }
      },
```

```
// attached
      {
        "partId": "1",
        "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
        "filename": "unnamed.jpeg",
        "headers": [
          {
            "name": "Content-Type",
            "value": "image/jpeg; name=\"unnamed.jpeg\""
          },
          {
            "name": "Content-Disposition",
            "value": "attachment; filename=\"unnamed.jpeg\""
          },
          {
            "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
            "value": "base64"
          },
          {
            "name": "Content-ID",
            "value": "\u003cf_l83jtl4x0\u003e"
          },
          {
            "name": "X-Attachment-Id",
            "value": "f_l83jtl4x0"
          }
        ],
        "body": {
          "attachmentId": "ANGjdJ_6KFGMzvKW6XFwD4BaSjCDSQGWPEMpL97DE1Lx31cKi2cSzSTOMDIdTEV8wyvnLiB8iqg5_1CVlDOOofl4NiEll2IwrxDuE-IdDXP9PmryOXbMp0pFgIQ961UQWQk8yhObqPcx8xWnqQaPWI3pwirH6hhoe3JtswoLXQ1NDs7FjJZ2iivLZHoTvMlh-i4VQIK6JVaEdIcQBejI6WruTi7DuC_ZpRwewfReZ2JsPKtncVCFwOkb0Ov1vElLS7Y1BTATiRzurXQw1A4lYOn5-XDKqXk90p_HxEQO5zEsvdz2MigVSa803-mIvK8RFTyOOuA4iVWEzad0I3mEFVE6bxTfFQ_YnAYm1FLKImnMEkJf5MuyZofZleyu8fjTGGqzvWmjikDGLvAzdM2O",
          "size": 1553427
        }
      }
```

UPDATE:

Max mentioned 'Content-ID', I can confirm it works for some emails I have, here is an example:

```
// header of the attachment part
{
  "name": "Content-ID",
  "value": "\u003cii_l83jb7dh0\u003e"
}

// decoded HTML body
<img src="cid:ii_l83jb7dh0" alt="20190906-2P2A3622.jpeg" width="361" height="542"><br>
```

Comment: @Max Thanks, feel free to post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. By the way, it just doesn't sound efficient because I will need to base64 decode the HTML body, and then search the CID string for each attachment to confirm that.

Comment: @HaoXi The `Content-Disposition` is *supposed* to tell you if its `inline` or not, but its not always used correctly, so you just have to buckle down and do some deeper analysis of how the attachment is actually being used in the rest of the email. At the very least, if the attachment is inside of a `multipart/related` MIME part then it is likely `inline` since it *should* be "related" to another MIME part (*usually* a 'text/html' MIME part). But that is not a guarantee. Neither is the fact that the attachment has a `Content-ID` assigned, since that ID may or may not actually be referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the only thing that distinguishes them is whether the Content-ID is referenced in the HTML body of the message. More precisely, by any reasonable definition, that image is an attachment, but it may also be referenced as a `cid:` url in an `<img>` tag in an HTML mime part. The header information alone cannot tell you that.